# How to get a tutoring position in Melbourne, Australia?

Tags: phd, teaching, australia, tutoring

I'm starting my PhD in neuroscience next month at the University of Melbourne and I've been told that graduate research students often work part time as tutors. I've been trying to find this information on the website but haven't really found anything. Would anyone be able to help me figure out how to go about getting a tutoring position for some extra cash and teaching experience? I've seen websites like learntmate etc., any recommendations for the best one and the process?

Comment: Are you talking about private tutoring external to the university, or being a teaching assistant for courses that your department teaches?

Comment: Both actually, I'd prefer the latter but essentially would be great to get paid a little more since PhD students make peanuts.

Answer (score 2):

**Wait, and you'll be contacted.**

Start your PhD first. Once you're officially a student, when they're looking for tutors, they'll send a mass email to all PhD students. That's when you can sign up. These are internal emails - the positions are not advertised online, and you won't be able to find them via Google.

If you're still concerned, you can ask your prospective supervisor or the department receptionist.

Comment: I was told by the university helpline that all positions are advertised on the careers unimelb page but I didn't see any. She also said that she isn't aware of positions being advertised anywhere else. I did see some private ones though (none for my subjects). 

Is it hard to get a tutoring position? More specifically, do they only take very few people?

Comment: @Divyangana this will depend entirely on the university (in mine, for instance, we don't have a choice: all PhD students must do some teaching). So wait, or ask your supervisor.

Comment: Which university are you at? I think that that's the case in the US but probably not in Australia.

Comment: @DivyanganaRakesh I'm pretty sure it applies in Australia as well. If you think it doesn't, then ask your prospective supervisor or the department receptionist.